# Get text or index of item from combobox with contains

Tags: c#, combobox, contains

I have a combobox and the items of the group membership look like

- 200;Heater
- 300;Cooler
- 400;Fan

If I select a part, only the number of the membership e.g. 200 is stored in the database.

Now I want to do a pre selection of the combobox.
To check if the combobox contains a membership number is working.

```
 void MembershipPreSelection(ComboBox cb, string text)
 {
    if (cb.Items.Cast<Part>().Any(c => c.Membership.Contains(text)))
        {
            // now I want the string for the item that contains the text.
        }
  }
```

But to get the text of the combobox item (e.g. 200;Heater)??
This is what I tried, but I do not get the item text.

`string m = cb.Items.Cast<Part>().Where(c => c.Hauptbaugruppe.Contains(text)).ToString();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest issue seems to be using `Where` in your `Linq` statement which will return a *collection* of `Part`. Then, when the `ToString()` is called on the result, it's probably is something cryptic like:

*System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[your_namespace.Part]*

To fix, consider something like `First` or `Single` in place of `Where` to return a single item.

```
string m = 
    cb.Items.Cast<Part>().Single(c => c.Hauptbaugruppe.Contains(text)).ToString();
```

---

You've probably already done this, but make sure that you have an  override to `Part.ToString()` that returns the format that you want.

```
// Example Part class
class Part
{
    public int ID { get; set; } = 0;
    public string Description { get; set; } = "New Item";
    
    // What do you want to see for `Part.ToString()`
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"ID: {ID} Description: {Description}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for letting me know that it worked! In general, please don't forget that if you find some useful information in an answer you could  give it an upvote. If an answer solves your problem you could click '✔' to mark it as an acceptable answer. [StackOverflow Help - Why Vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Comment: Thx for this information. I didn't know that until now.